# Display a custom text if user has already bought the current product In Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In woocommerce I use wc_customer_bought_product() function to display a custom text message in single product pages when customer has already bought the current product. but I would like to check that the product(s) bought are on orders with "completed" status.

The message is not supposed to be shown unless the following criteria is met:

1. user is logged in
2. user has purchased the product
3. At least one placed order for the current product is set to complete (what I cannot figure out how to get done).

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woo_review_discount_message');
function woo_review_discount_message() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $product;

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() && $order->status->complete ) ) 
            echo '<div class="user-bought"><span style="color:#CA364D;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"><i class="wishlist-icon icon-heart-o"></i></span> Hi ' . $current_user->first_name . '! Please write a review below.</a></div>';
    }
}
```

I tried adding `&& $order->status->complete` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target **only Orders with a complete status**, you can use the following custom conditional function based on [`wc_customer_bought_product()` source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_customer_bought_product.html#202-259):

```
// Utility function to check if a customer has bought a product (Order with "completed" status only)
function customer_has_bought_product( $product_id, $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 || $user_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $status      = 'wc-completed';

    if( ! $customer_id )
        return false;

    // Count the number of products
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(woim.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status = '$status'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND woim.meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id')
        AND woim.meta_value = $product_id
    " );

    // Return a boolean value if count is higher than 0
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woo_review_discount_message');
function woo_review_discount_message() {
    global $product;

    if ( customer_has_bought_product( $product->get_id() ) && ! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo '<div class="user-bought"><span style="color:#CA364D;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"><i class="wishlist-icon icon-heart-o"></i></span> Hi ' . $user->first_name . '! Please write a review below.</a></div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

If customer is not logged in nothing will be displayed.

> Like Woocommerce function `wc_customer_bought_product()`, this will not work on variable products single pages.

Comment: WOW, that is awesome. All that is left to check for is if the customer has written a review or not for the product and if not, show the message. If review is written, do not show message.

I have that question in another question since you previously said that this check only on completed could not be done. If I did something wrong asking "twice" I'm sorry. That question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050736/checking-if-customer-wrote-a-review-or-not-in-woocommerce

If you can help with that I would be very happy.

Comment: "Thank you" says WooAngel to @WooDevil :)

Comment: :) Thanks and your welcome. I'm trying to get around this, finding a way to make it check if the customer bought the product but did not write a review, then show the message. If they bought it and wrote a review, do not show it.

That is my "big goal" now that I finally got some help with making it work only on "completed".