# Check if customer wrote a review for a product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, review

This code will check if the customer is logged in, if he/she purchased the product and if those statements are true, it will display a message.

I would like to include one more check before the message is shown and that is if the customer already left a review/ wrote a review for the product and if so, do not show the message.

In other words, if the customer did not write a review for the product, show message. If customer left a review, do not show message.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woo_review_discount_message');
function woo_review_discount_message() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $product;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() && $order->status->complete ) ) echo '<div class="user-bought"><span style="color:#CA364D;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"><i class="wishlist-icon icon-heart-o"></i></span> Hi ' . $current_user->first_name . '! Please write a review below.</a></div>';
}
}
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a customer has posted a review on the current product, you will use this custom conditional function (using a very light SQL query):

```
// Utility function to check if a customer has posted a review in a product
function has_reviewed_product( $product_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $user->ID == 0 )
        return false;

    // Count the number of products
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}comments
        WHERE comment_post_ID = $product_id
        AND comment_author_email = '{$user->user_email}'
    " );

    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

So in your code *(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048413/display-a-custom-text-if-user-has-already-bought-the-current-product-in-woocomme))* you will use it as following:

```
// Utility function to check if a customer has bought a product (Order with "completed" status only)
function customer_has_bought_product( $product_id, $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 || $user_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $status      = 'wc-completed';

    if( ! $customer_id )
        return false;

    // Count the number of products
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(woim.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status = '$status'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND woim.meta_value = $product_id
    " );

    // Return a boolean value if count is higher than 0
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woo_review_discount_message');
function woo_review_discount_message() {
    global $product;

    if ( customer_has_bought_product( $product->get_id() ) && ! $product->is_type('variable') && ! has_reviewed_product( $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo '<div class="user-bought"><span style="color:#CA364D;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"><i class="wishlist-icon icon-heart-o"></i></span> Hi ' . $user->first_name . '! Please write a review below.</a></div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related answer: [Display a custom text if user has already bought the current product In Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048413/display-a-custom-text-if-user-has-already-bought-the-current-product-in-woocomme/53051339#53051339)

Comment: The code seem to work but I cannot leave a review. When I try, it re-directs me to my IP number followed by /$

Comment: tested on a different site and it works fine. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I'm sorry for spamming you, but would you mind taking a look at this when you can?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030518/happy-birthday-message-for-woocommerce-customers