# Display customer unreviewed purchased products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I would be grateful for help. I have a code that displays the purchased products of the current user in the [customer_products] shortcode.

I need to check the content of the shortcode to see if the user left a review on their purchased products.

1. If the user left a review for the purchased product, the product is not shown in the shortcode.
2. If the user did not leave a review for the purchased product, the product(products without reviews) in the shortcode is show, and display the text.

Please help, I am a beginner in php, I understand that I need the has_reviewed_product function, as it is used in another answer:
[Check if customer wrote a review for a product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050736/check-if-customer-wrote-a-review-for-a-product-in-woocommerce/)

But I don't understand how to write this check in the output code of the shortcode.

Thank you all very much for your help.

```
add_shortcode( 'customer_products', 'rrr_products_current_user' );
 
function rrr_products_current_user() {
    
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
 
    
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
    ) );
 
    
    if ( ! $customer_orders ) {
        return;
    }
 
    
    $ids = array();
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
        }
    }
 
    
    return do_shortcode( '[products ids="' . join( ",", array_unique( $ids ) ) . '"]' );
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `wc_get_order()` function, as WooCommerce orders will have very soon their own tables in the WordPress database.

The following shortcode will only display unreviewed purchased product(s) for a customer, **assuming** that in WooCommerce Settings > Product > Reviews, you have enabled "Reviews can only be left by "verified owners" option:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
// Utility function that get the reviewved products Ids of a customer
function get_customer_reviewed_products( $user_email ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Returns an array of product Ids reviewed by the customer
    return $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT c.comment_post_ID 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}comments as c
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID 
        WHERE c.comment_author_email = '{$user_email}'
            AND p.post_type = 'product'
    " );
}

// The custom products shortcode
add_shortcode( 'customer_products', 'customer_products_shortcode' );
function customer_products_shortcode() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // GEt WP_User  object
    
    // Get customer orders
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'         => -1,
        'customer'      => $user->ID,
        'status'        => wc_get_is_paid_statuses(),
    ) );

    $product_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through customer orders
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $customer_order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product_ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
        }
    }
 
    if ( empty($customer_orders) ){
        return;
    }

    // Get customer reviewed products ids
    $reviewed_ids = get_customer_reviewed_products( $user->user_email );
    
    // Keep only customer unreviewed purchased products
    $ids = implode( ',', array_diff( array_unique( $product_ids ), $reviewed_ids ) );
    
    return do_shortcode( "[products ids='$ids']" );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Usage:**

In WordPress Text editors, Widgets or Blocks:

```
[customer_products]
```

Or in PHP:

```
echo do_shortcode("[customer_products]");
```